# Can I produce llvm bytecode from asm(example mips asm)?

Tags: assembly, llvm, mips, bytecode

I have some mips asm code and i want to port it to x86(with some edit of course) I decided to look aside llvm. Buy i can't find anything about how to translate asm in to llvm bytecode.

Comment: I don't know if there are any decompilers that decompile asm to LLVM-IR.  There might be, but I don't think any come with LLVM.

Comment: The LLVM is sort of abstract language (although quite "low level"), so there's no guarantee the original MIPS binary can be translated into LLVM. It may contain constructs which are not possible to recreate in LLVM, and I'm not talking about 1:1 projection to get identical binary (that sounds completely off limits), but about actually any machine tool being incapable to recreate the original code in functionality-identical way. So I wouldn't expect plethora of asm/binary -> llvm tools, and even if something would exist, the result would surely need manual retuning/fixing to make sense/work.